# grep output of cdrecord

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep, wodim

I would like to parse the output of cdrecord/wodim using grep. `cdrecord -v` outputs lines like

```
Track 01:   49 of   75 MB written (fifo 100%) [buf 100%]  10.2x.
```

The problem is that cdrecord uses carriage returns (`CR`, `\r`) in order to show the progress in the same line.

I tried to append `tr '\r' '\n'` to the cdrecord call, which works generally, but the output won't show line by line. Instead, large chunks of text are parsed and displayed:

```
cdrecord -v ... | tr '\r' '\n' | grep -i written
```

Is this due to cdrecord, tr or grep? Is there any way to force flushing in order to get the output line by line?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: IIRC `tr` and `grep` both are buffered..you can try `cdrecord -v ... | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n' | grep --line-buffered -i written`

Comment: @heemayl: thank you very much! Works like a charm! However, the `--line-buffered` option of grep only works on grep's output, so I guess this is unnecessary.

Comment: Right.. Answer added..

Comment: Important here is that cdrecord calls fflush(stdout) to update a line. This is sufficient for all GUI implementations that parse the output in order to convert it into a growing bar window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of `tr` is buffered. You can use `stdbuf -o0` with `tr` to make it's STDOUT unbuffered:

```
cdrecord -v ... | stdbuf -o0 tr '\r' '\n' | grep -i written
```